# Pass value to other function MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a Public function with 2 parameter. I want to pass the Id to Order() function. I call details() in order(). But its doesnt work. Is there any way to do this?

```
Public Function details(Name As String, Id As String) As ActionResult
...
Return(nothing,Id)
End Function

Private Function Order(Id As String) As List(Of Order)
details(nothing,Id)
End Function
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or anything else?

Comment: there is no error. It supposed to display the value but it is blank. In details() there is a SQL statement that will return a list. Return View(order.ToList())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [tempData](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/476967/whatplusisplusviewdata-cplusviewbagplusandplustem) instead of Viewbag

Answer (score 0):

details function return type is action Result and AS Per Documentation

A common action result is obtained by calling the View method, which returns an instance of the ViewResult class. The ViewResult derives from ActionResult. In that case, the return type of the action method is ActionResult, but an instance of the ViewResult class is returned

public ActionResult details(int id)
        {

```
       ViewBag.orders=Order(id);
```

return View();
        }

Comment: I want to return both view and value

Comment: Then Call action Result method (details) first (through View) and in that method call order which return view and list

Comment: Yes I already called the method through view. It displays the view that I want. The problem is, the Id parameter are not being passed. It return a blank textbox.

Comment: you can also pass id in viewBag

Comment: I want to pass it in the controller. Is it something wrong using this code `details(nothing,Id)` ?

Comment: I have Updated The answer and yes u cannot call method directly which return actionResult

Comment: How would i call the id in the other function?

Comment: Haven't u check my updated answer? and plz upvote if it helps you

Comment: I am using tempData instead of ViewBag. Thanks for your response